# 27 year-old Canadian citizen looking to move to UK (can prove both grandfathers are UK citizens)

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, canada, uk-citizens

Do I need to get a job prior to my application for the UK Visa? The [UK Ancestry Visa page](https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa) says I need an offer, but I'm wondering how firm this is.

Can I go the UK and stay for a few months while I look for work? I work at a hedge fund, and am looking to do something similar in the UK. Of course I won't be travelling soon. I'm hoping for some time in early 2021.

Comment: I don't see anything on the linked page (nor on any page linked therefrom) that says an applicant for a UK Ancestry Visa must "have an offer."  Where do you see that requirement?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: I wondered that too, and found on https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa/documents-you-must-provide it says "evidence that you’re planning to work in the UK, for example job offers you’ve received or a business plan if you’re self-employed".

Answer (score 4):

> The UK Ancestry Visa page ( https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa ) says I need an offer

That is not correct.  It says that you need "evidence that you’re planning to work in the UK."

It then goes on to give examples of such evidence, one of which is "job offers you’ve received."

You can submit other evidence instead, but I do not know how concrete the evidence needs to be.  For example, evidence that you plan to look for a job may or may not be sufficient; evidence that you actually have been looking for jobs may or may not be sufficient.

Comment: More explicit guidance on the employment requirement is available here https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/845201/uk-ancestry-v17.0-ext.pdf#page17

Answer (score 3):

The Answer posted by @phoog is correct, and is explained in more detail by the UK Ancestry Guidance cited in Traveller's comment. Page 17 of 37 of the Guidance says:

> The applicant does not have to be working at the time they apply. They need only demonstrate they are able to work and intend to take and seek employment. Evidence of this could include, but is not limited to:
>
> - job offers from employers
> - evidence of registration with a recruitment agency
> - evidence of job applications they have made or any steps they have
>   undertaken to improve their chances of finding employment – for example,
>   relevant training courses
> - a business plan, if they intend to be self-employed